# When I type in the domain i bought from Godaddy it resolves to my wordpress from EC2 but it then switches to the Elastic IP for that EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress, godaddy, amazon-route53, dns-hosting

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvi7X.jpg

I created an elastic IP so the public IP would be fixed. I then attached the A type with @ name in Godaddy and the 4 servers for custom nameservers as you can see in the picture. When I type in my domain URL i bought in godaddy, like e.g. myhotdog.com, it resolves to my wordpress site i installed in that EC2 instance but then it changes back to the IP like e.g. '18.xx.xx.220'.

What am i not doing right here!?

Thanks, Dhivash

Comment: Whats in your address settings in Wordpress? Did you set your domain name in Wordpress itself?

Comment: See the answer someone posted.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you need to configure Wordpress to use the hostname, with `SiteAdress` and `WordPress Adress`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL